# Python pygame.mixer does not play music infinitely

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I want to play an alarm wave file continuously until it detects a button is pushed.  In this case I use a keyboard interrupt to try.

Here is my script:

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("beep.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
print "Time to take medicine!"

try:
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        continue

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

However it only played once and it stops and exits the script. What's wrong?

**UPDATE:** 
I manage to let it run and terminate upon keyboard interrupt but I don't understand why `play(-1)` doesn't work?

This is my working script:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("beep.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
print "Time to take medicine!"

while True:
    try:
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            continue

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: +1.This is a mystery to me also. It might be a bug

Answer (score 0):

pygame manual says about

```
pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()
```

> Returns True when the music stream is actively playing. When the music
>   is idle this returns False.

So the problem is, that this functions returns False in the little gap when the sound ends and is going to start again. This is the reason your 2nd version works.